# JComboBox ExecuteQuery selecting Items error

Tags: java, sqlite

I have 3 jComboBox. The first one is for the Room Type. When I select Room Type on the first jComboBox it must show in the second jComboBox all the available room, but when I select one of the Room Type, an error pops u.p

[image: https://imgur.com/a/wpmhLfD]

Here is the code for actionperformed on the first jComboBox

first jComboBox actionperformed*

```
    if(jComboBox13.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("SELECT")){

    }else{
            try{
            String like = jComboBox13.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String sql = "Select * From Room_Master\n" +
                         "inner join Room_Type on Room_Master.Room_Type_ID=Room_Type.Room_Type_ID\n" +
                         "where Room_Type = '"+like+"'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            jComboBox14.removeAllItems();
            jComboBox14.addItem("SELECT");
        while(rs.next()){
            String add1 = rs.getString("Room_No.");
            jComboBox14.addItem(add1);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }finally {
            try {
               rs.close();
               pst.close();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
```

second jComboBox actionperformed

```
if(jComboBox14.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("SELECT") | jComboBox14.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty()){

    }else{
            try{

            String like = jComboBox14.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String sql = "Select * from Bed_Master\n" +
                         "inner join Room_Master on Bed_Master.Room_ID=Room_Master.Room_ID\n" +
                         "where [Room_No.] = '"+like+"'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            jComboBox15.removeAllItems();
            jComboBox15.addItem("SELECT");
        while(rs.next()){
            String add1 = rs.getString("Bed_No.");
            jComboBox15.addItem(add1);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
               rs.close();
               pst.close();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
```

but after i select another Room type it will work
i tried to remove "combobox.removeAllItems();"
but it will keep addding all the items in the jCombobox
almost 1 week trying to figure it out can someone help please

Comment: It seems you are getting a `NullPointerException`. Please add the stack trace of that exception to the question. (To get that stack trace, you have to add `e.printStackTrace();` to the first `catch` block in your code.)

Comment: I would remove the `.` from `rs.getString("Room_No.");`

Comment: can you help me with this? what should I do ?

Comment: Huh? I just told you.

Comment: if i remove that how can i put items on the jComboBox?

Comment: OK lets say again in a different way so it is easier to understand - change `String add1 = rs.getString("Room_No.");` **TO** `String add1 = rs.getString("Room_No");`

Comment: the name of the Column on that table have ( dot ) on it so if i remove it. it will give me errors

Comment: OK, do not silently swallow your Exceptions. change to `catch(Exception e){  e.printStackTrace ();

            }`  then we will know what the real problem is

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yHi7lhK

Comment: and please post as text in future

Comment: do you mean 6966?

Comment: if(jComboBox14.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("SELECT") | jComboBox14.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty()){
            
        }

Comment: the problem is when I select on the first jComboBox the second jcombobox is empty but when i select again on the first jCombobox the second jComboBox item appear

Answer (score 1):

When you call `removeAllItems` it fires the actionListener for `jComoboBox14`
and at this stage it will not have any Items so `getSelected` will return `NULL`

change your `if` to

```
if(jComboBox14.getItemCount() > 0 && (jComboBox14.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("SELECT") |
                                             jComboBox14.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty())){
```

Comment: is there any way that when I select on first jComboBox it will not set the second jComboBox to empty

Comment: don't call `removeAllItems` ?

Comment: but it will stay and duplicate items inside the jCombobox sir

Comment: If you follow the code as posted in my answer, it will solve your problem (will need to be extended for the other cases too)

Comment: Well i that case please post the code that you have, so more debugging can be done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You should give your objects variables an useful name:
Ex: `jComboBox13 --> JComboBox comboRoomsType  = new JComboBox();` or whatever name you prefer.

Then, it would be nice to see all the code involved. I can't see where you initialize the `ResultSet` or `PreparedStatement`;

I GUESS the NullPointer comes from the select statement, when trying to retrieve the values.

```
if(jComboBox13.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("SELECT")){

}else{
        try{
        String like = jComboBox13.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String sql = "Select * From Room_Master RM " +
                     "inner join Room_Type RT on RM.Room_Type_ID=RT.Room_Type_ID " 
                     +"where Room_Type = '"+like+"'";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        jComboBox14.removeAllItems();
        jComboBox14.addItem("SELECT");
     //you can also check if there are values first.
    while(rs.hasNext()){
        rs.next();
        String add1 = rs.getString("Room_No");
       //You can also use 
       //String add1 = rs.getInt(number of column of <Room_No> );
        jComboBox14.addItem(add1);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }finally {
        try {
           rs.close();
           pst.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DummyDummy Add the Room Type value that causes the error pls.